# Refresh desktop icon of mac os x

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, desktop-application

I want to refresh desktop icon of my application without relaunch finder or dock. my motive is refresh desktop icon without realize refresh to user

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
tell application "Finder"
    tell desktop
        update every item with necessity
    end tell
end tell
```

Refresh apple script does not work on 10.8 and above. Only way to refresh desktop is to restart finder.

Comment: it refresh finder, i want something which refresh desktop icon without realize refresh , when finder is refreshed it clearly visible by user